# ActiveRecord Migrations Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following migration:

```
create_table :dynamic_variables do |t|
  t.integer id null: false
  t.integer section_id null: false
  t.string name
  t.string display_name
  t.string fallback_value
  t.string current_value
  t.text possible_values
  t.boolean is_active default: 1
  t.boolean is_archived  default: 0
  t.timestamp last_activity
  t.timestamps null: false
```

1. How do I define the id in the first row as the primary key?
2. How do I set two attributes in one of the columns, for example, the is_archived default value is 0 and it also cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation: `A primary key column called id will also be added implicitly, as it's the default primary key for all Active Record models...`
You can pass parameters to the column like this:

```
is_archived, default: 0, null: false
```

More information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html